# How to fix warning '/boot/efi` is full

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

Since recently I get confronted straight after boot with a message saying that the partition `/boot/efi` is full.
Which files in below list can i safely remove, leaving the system in a properly working state?
The machine is running Ubuntu 20.04, and dual boots into Windows. I have ignored mentioned message, but I would like the annoying message to disappear.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248245 apr 12 20:47 config-5.8.0-50-generic
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     1024 jan  1  1970 efi/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 apr 28 15:58 grub/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 apr 22 12:44 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 57200439 mei  7 09:50 initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 apr 26 09:35 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5531453 apr 12 20:47 System.map-5.8.0-50-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 apr 22 12:44 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  9785696 apr 12 22:17 vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 apr 26 09:35 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
```

Comment: Clear out old kernels with `sudo apt autoremove` and remove older Linux kernels that may be present.  `/boot/` should also not be 'full' unless it's been sized far too small for you to use.  How large is your `/boot/` partition?

Comment: You are showing /boot, not /boot/efi. Your ESP - EFI system partition is mounted at /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu and will have /EFI/Microsoft for Windows UEFI boot file.  Post this: `df -h`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment on answers yet due to lack of reputation points, therefor do I comment through adding an `answer` instead.

@Thomas Ward, thanks for your answer, I ran `sudo apt autoremove`, that didn't remove anything at first glance.

@oldfred, here are the results of `df -h`:

```
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3,2G  5,0M  3,1G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6  650G  171G  447G  28% /
tmpfs            16G  189M   16G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/nvme0n1p2   96M   94M  2,9M  98% /boot/efi
/dev/loop1      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop3       52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop6      139M  139M     0 100% /snap/krita/63
/dev/loop7       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop4       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop5      261M  261M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
/dev/loop8       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop9      241M  241M     0 100% /snap/zoom-client/142
/dev/loop10      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11588
/dev/loop11     241M  241M     0 100% /snap/zoom-client/143
tmpfs           3,2G   32K  3,2G   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           3,2G   52K  3,2G   1% /run/user/1000
```